# Separate a String and check if the string is the key of array in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, key

I am trying to separate them all according to white space.

```
$string = "1 2 3 10 12";
```

According to this string, I want to separate like that.

```
$a = "1";
$b = "2";
$c = "3";
$d = "10";
$e = "12";
```

After that, I would like to check those strings are included as the key of an array. Here is my array,

```
$data = [
"1" => "Book",
"2" => "Paper",
"3" => "Pencil",
"10" => "Eraser",
"11" => "Ruler",
];
```

So, How can I separate an array and store the parts in each variable?
And How to check those variable are included in array as a key? Sorry for my English :D. Thanks.

Comment: any attempt made? Tried exploding using space?

Comment: I try to separate a string using str_replace(), preg_replace() function. But I can't get as i want :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to seperate the values and then check if the array key exists using [array key exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).

```
$stringArray = explode(" ",$string);

foreach($stringArray as $stringPeice){
   if(array_key_exists($stringPeice, $data)){
     //do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I will try again. Thanks.

Comment: There's multiple ways of doing it. It all depends on how you want to process that data after. If you need to check indidual string for something, my answer is most relevant. However if you need to check the array as a whole use @sevavietl answer.

Comment: Yes, I want to show only the value that the separated string is as the key in array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to create an array of keys and then use [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to get an array of keys that are not in the `$data`:

```
$string = "1 2 3 10 12";

$keys = explode(' ', $string);

$data = [
    "1" => "Book",
    "2" => "Paper",
    "3" => "Pencil",
    "10" => "Eraser",
    "11" => "Ruler",
];

$diff = array_diff($keys, array_keys($data));
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a7708cd46575d1decd347861e79727c98f1b85e6).

Comment: Thank you. I will try to use that test function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the entries from `$data` whose key exists in `$string`, you can use `array_intersect_key()`, and `array_fill_keys()` to create an array containing keys from the result of exploding `$string`:

```
$o = array_intersect_key($data, array_fill_keys(explode(" ", $string), ""));
```

#### [Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/K6rlq)

Comment: Thanks. I will test this code too, and learn more about array function in php.